# Can a subsequence of a convergence sum converge anywhere?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This question seems basic but I couldn't find an answer :

> Let $a_n$ be a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers such that the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$$ converges to $a$ . Then is it true that there is some $b$ with $0<b<a$ such that for every subsequence $b_n$ of $a_n$ the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i$$ doesn't converges to $b$ ?

I thought about it a little and I think the answer is yes but I couldn't find a proof .

**My approach**

Choose the terms of the sequence $b_n$ in a greedy way :

If you have already chosen $b_1,b_2,\ldots b_{n-1}$ then choose $b_n$ the largest number such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i< b$$  Then I think that at some point even if you'll choose all the numbers remaining in $a_n$ you won't make it to the number $b$ .

This is true for a 'fast' decreasing sequence like $\frac{1}{n^2}$ :

$$1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\ldots=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Let's take $b=0.9$ . It's obvious that you can't choose $1$ and all the other terms together have a sum of $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1<0.9$ so $b=0.9$ won't work .

This can be generalized for all sequences with $a_1 > a-a_1 $ .

This is all I found . Thanks for your help with this question.

Comment: @WojciechKarwacki  So you mean to take $d$ and $e$ the two biggest elements and then $b=\frac{d+e}{2}$ will satisfy the property ? Why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$. Then for every $b$ with $0\lt b\lt 1$ there is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ whose sum converges to $b$.

Comment: It is worth noting, perhaps, that the property *does* hold for $a_n = r^{n}$ when $r < 1/2$

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Binary writing is undoubtedly awesome .

Comment: You  are welcome.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but doesn't every subsequence of $(a_n)$ converge to 0?

Comment: Yes, every subsequence of $(a_n)$ converges to $0$. However, your question is about *sums* of subsequences.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I took the liberty of changing the wording in your answer slightly, but please change it back if you want to.

Comment: @user84413: Thanks for altering from what I said to what I meant to say!